# Can CodeBuild can access object metadata inside codepipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to access S3 objects user-defined metadata inside codebuild and set as environment variable.

As per [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-S3.html#action-reference-S3-variables), it only output etag and VersionId. **So I am assuming by default user defined metadata is not exported to codepipeline when s3 is a source action**

I am thinking to use aws cli command and then set this as environment variable for the codebuild. Is there a better way?

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket bucket-name --profile profile --key xxxx.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right: the only way to get the object metadata is to use a `head-object` CLI call. You can use the below buildspec in your CodeBuild stage to get the object metadata for a pipeline with s3 source action.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - BUCKET_PATH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -d ':' -f 6)
      - BUCKET=$(echo $BUCKET_PATH | cut -d '/' -f 1)
      - KEY=$(echo $BUCKET_PATH | cut -d '/' -f 2,3,4)
      - aws s3api head-object --bucket $BUCKET --key $KEY --query Metadata
```

Please note that updating metadata on the s3 source object will also trigger the pipeline with s3 source action.

Comment: I am using jq that is more sleek!